# Glassfish Datasource Connections

Tags: database, jdbc, connection, glassfish, datasource

We're using glassfish 3.1.2 and it seems very brittle in terms of maintaining datasource connection pools through a database server restart or a break in network connectivity with the database (even a slight one).

It doesn't seem like it's particularly adept and re-establishing those connections and moving on.

We're using com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource.

We're using connection validation.

Is there something else we're missing?   Does anyone else experience this?

Answer (score 0):

Same here.

Have you tried to configure the JDBC connection with autoreconnect?
Example: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/foo?autoReconnect=true